# Recursively remove all nodes of the tree

Tags: c, recursion, tree

```
/*
Recursively remove all nodes of the tree
*/
void dispose(node* root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        dispose(root->left);
        dispose(root->right);
        free(root);
    }
}
```

I don't understand how this code deletes a whole tree.

What I see is it recursively goes to the left node until it reaches a null node, then goes to the right node, then keeps going to the left again till null, then to the right and if null then free the parent.

It seems it deletes the last leaf of a tree instead of the whole thing,

Could someone explain the process of code as I tried to above if I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can help a lot to write out the sequence of function calls that will be made as your program executes.  Here's an example tree:

```
            A
    B               C
D       E       F       G
```

For this tree, the sequence of function calls will be:

```
dispose(A)
    dispose(B)
        dispose(D)
            dispose(NULL)
            dispose(NULL)
            free(D)
        dispose(E)
            dispose(NULL)
            dispose(NULL)
            free(E)
        free(B)
    dispose(C)
        dispose(F)
            dispose(NULL)
            dispose(NULL)
            free(F)
        dispose(G)
            dispose(NULL)
            dispose(NULL)
            free(G)
        free(C)
    free(A)
```